# How to migrate from Sqlite to PostgresSQL in Django? OperationalError

Tags: django, django-models

**I am learning to use Django through a tutorial in which we are developing a small project,**
**i'm trying to connect a PostgresSQL database and do the migrations,**
**but i have certain problems when doing 'python manage.py migrate' in the terminal**

**Settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DEMO_TEST',
        'USER' : 'postgresql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD':'le123le123',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Traceback**

```
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1290, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1680, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", line 93, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

**Create the account in PostgreSQL and try to link it with Django to have the tables that I have already created in Sqlite3. Someone help me please**

Comment: Make sure your postgresql server has started and is running. Do you work on windows or linux ?

Comment: I dont know bro, im working in windows... Can you explain me? @monio

Comment: Try to run "pgAdmin 4" from startmenu (server should start) and try to run migration.

Comment: The 'pgadmin 4' server starts perfectly in Chrome, but I go to the terminal and type 'python manage.py migrate' in the project directory and I get the same error... The same thing happens if I want to turn on the python server @monio

Comment: Download and install database shell in your system then first create database ```create database DEMO_TEST``` and then try..

Comment: Oh yea, make sure you create your database  `DEMO_TEST` first - you can do it in pgAdmin.

Comment: I already have the database created in 'pgAdmin' but the problem continues @TariqAhmed

Comment: I already have the database created in 'pgAdmin' but the problem continues @monio

Comment: Maybe username or password is bad - try username `postgres`

Comment: I opened the postgre session again in 'pgadmin' and tried again to do the migrations, however the problem persists... But something that I noticed in the tutorial is that they create the database in 'LOCALHOST', when I did it in 'SERVER' because in the pgadmin dashboard it did not give me the option of 'LOCALHOST' ... That would have something that watch? @monio